# openldap SSL/TLS Cert: Get a 'real' one or use Self Signed?

Tags: linux, ssl, openldap

I'm setting up SSL/TLS on OpenLDAP and wondering why the [Debian Handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.ldap-directory.html) has the user create a self-signed cert? Wouldn't one signed by a 'real' CA be more secure?

Comment: Do your LDAP clients actually verify the certificate off of a list of trusted roots? If not, it does not matter. Even if they do, certs signed by a trusted CA are no more "secure" than self-signed certs.

Comment: That depends... is the "real" CA charging you $100 or $500 to sign your cert?  I ask because obviously the $500 signatures are more secure.

Comment: Ok... so... The answer would be 'no' then.. Not sure I follow EEAA's argument but will google it.

Comment: The price of a certificate has nothing to do with security, but with marketing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this depends entirely on who and what is connecting to your LDAP server.  Every client that connects via LDAPS **SHOULD** verify that the certificate is signed by a trusted authority.  Not all of them do.  (This is what EEAA is referring to)  A self signed certificate will not be trusted by default.  So it will need to be imported into the list of trusted authorities to work properly.

If the machine/software that is going to be connecting to your LDAP server is under your administrative control, then self-signed is viable.  You'll need to import your certificate into the trust store for that application.  (OS level, Java JVM cacerts, et al)  This can range from trivial (eg: Windows with GroupPolicy), to extremely irritating (HP printers can use LDAP for E-Mailing scans...and they're terrible with certificates).  If you've got BYOD/random uncontrolled machines using this LDAP server...then the trusted CA cert should just 'work' for them, without clicking through warnings, or importing certificates.